# Nvidia drivers problem (not booting, nvidia-smi not detecting etc.)

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, graphics, modprobe

I am at my wits end with Nvidia drivers. I believe that I tried to set them up a long time ago, failed, and settled with open-source drivers. However, I still had to deal with screen tearing so after a year or so, I have decided to switch to propreitary drivers once and for all.

First, I made a file called `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` which consists of these two lines to block the kernel from loading the nouveau modules:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

I then ran `sudo update-initramfs -u` to update the changes.

Then, I typed the following commands to remove all existing nvidia drivers on my device:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^libnvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^cuda-.*'
```

Then, I added the nvidia drivers ppa using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers`. After doing that, I installed the most recent drivers using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530`.

However, now I am running into problems. Once I reboot and boot into Ubuntu (I am running a dual boot with Windows), I am faced with a black screen. I have to go into the tty1 terminal to interact with my system from this point. If I run `sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'` and reboot, my system loads up fine. Note that in the tty1 here (before I purge the nvidia drivers), nvidia-smi gives me output on my nvidia-drivers.

However, if I turn secure boot on (it was off previously), then I can load fine into the graphic log-in screen and use linux normally. However, now, if I run `nvidia-smi`, it will inform me that:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

So, I either can use my system but (apparently) without proper nvidia driver support or the drivers can be supported and read but the system won't load. I don't know how to fix this, any help?

**Debug information (with secure boot on, `nvidia-smi` can't read nvidia drivers)**

I am running ubuntu 20.04 LTS version.

The output of is `apt list --installed | grep nvidia` is

```
libnvidia-cfg1-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-common-530/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security,focal,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 all [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-extra-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 i386 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-compute-utils-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-dkms-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-driver-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-kernel-common-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-source-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-prime/focal-updates,focal-updates,now 0.8.16~0.20.04.2 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/focal-updates,focal,now 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-utils-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-530/focal-updates,focal-security,focal,now
```

The output of `lspci -v | grep "VGA controller"` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Comment: If it were *me* I would just reinstall the system. If you check "download updates" and "proprietary drivers" then the Ubuntu installer will configure the appropriate proprietary Nvidia driver and you won't need to do anything else. Unfortunately, after you've installed nouveau, you can have problems with proprietary. If you've ever downloaded and installed the driver's from Nvidia's website, they aren't compatible and are extremely difficult to clean up the mess they cause. The PPA has similar problems to the other two. Having done all? That's a big mess and will be hard to fix.

Comment: If you reinstall, and there are still problems, you can run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. If you still have problems, ask a new question with the details of the new attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly this same problem for RTX 4060 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. First, plug in an external monitor to your laptop.

Once you are able to get into tty terminal through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (during the black screen with white cursor on laptop), do:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

This is to initialize and generate your configuration parameters, as described here https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/nvidia-xconfig.1.html. The `nvidia-xconfig` command will generate nvidia configuration file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, if none exist before. You can look at what the config file looks like by doing `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, note the details.

To enable the gpu to recognize the external monitor, do:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus
```

This will examine the system and configures an X screen for each display device it finds. Do `nano` to check the config file again, you should now see the part that says Section `Device` with your NVIDIA GPU showing under the BoardName.

Then reboot your system:

```
sudo reboot
```

On starting back, the external monitor should now be displaying, while the laptop monitor remain in the black screen. You should be able to work fine with this for now until this is resolved by NVIDIA with an updated Linux kernel for the RTX 4060. Currently, the most up-to-date Kernel 5.15.0-84-generic is not working well with RTX 4060. This problem you have is widely reported - I have read a lot of it in the past one week since I had this issue (`Nvidia-smi failing to communicate`). Follow the steps in the link below here to update your kernel; I used the Liquorix in my "Other Software" for "ppa" as shown under Software & Updates. Find link here [https://launchpad.net/~damentz/+archive/ubuntu/liquorix](https://launchpad.net/%7Edamentz/+archive/ubuntu/liquorix)